# Wordpress comment cookies

Tags: wordpress, cookies

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies says that the user password is double-hashed. So when I post a comment and I'm not a user, what is hashed in the cookie?!?!?
On that particular blog I came from a link from facebook, if that`s counting.

Edit: 3 cookies

comment_author_email_dcd8acfba3c36c550xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
comment_author_url_dcd8acfba3c36c550xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx comment_author_dcd8acfba3c36c550xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the bottom section of that document, the one titled "Commenters."  The section you were reading applies only to users who have logged in to Wordpress.

**UPDATE:** The extra junk after the cookie name is still part of the cookie *name*, not the value.  I believe this is an identifier used to tell different Wordpress installations on the same domain apart, so they won't step on each other's cookies.

Comment: Ok, so based on that section, nothing is stored hashed in cookies.  Just your name, email address, and website.

Comment: That section contains *nothing* about a user password at all, Bakudan. It tells you exactly what is contained in the cookie. Read it again.